# Unix epoch time in fractional seconds to Joda DateTime

Tags: java, unix, datetime, jodatime

I have a unix timestamp that is expressed in fractional seconds, I need to convert this into a joda DateTime but I'm stuck with finding a right conversion format. Value looks like this 1403533177.806899 and when I try to parse this I'm getting the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1403533177.806899" is malformed at "7.806899"
```

This is the piece of code I'm using

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
dtf.parseDateTime(value);
```

I used the following conversion formats

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Using online epoch converter I don't have any problem converting this. Can anyone suggest me the right conversion string for this timestamp?

Comment: Include your java code in the question.

Comment: Also post value used for `'format'` variable.

Comment: As a workaround I'm discarding fractional part as of now to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you don't use date formatter for this, but some simple arithmetic instead:

```
long millis = Math.round(value * 1000);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(millis, DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(0));
```

This rounds your given seconds and microseconds to the nearest millisecond and creates a new `DateTime` instance based on that.

You have an epoch timestamp in seconds, while the JodaTime `DateTime` internal representation is also an epoch timestamp in milliseconds.

The formatter converts a human-readable date and time into an epoch, so it's really not what you need, it would just be a long way around.

If you need to print the value later, you can then use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
dtf.print(dt);
```

Comment: FWIW, I would use `floor` rather than `round` - it's generally not a good idea for a computer to think that time is more advanced than it is.

Comment: @Alnitak what do you mean by "time is more advanced than it is"? The input timestamp has 6 decimal places, indicating microsecond precision. Why lose precision in such a way?

Comment: I'd still keep it at millisecond precision - by "more advanced" I meant "in the future" (even if that is only by fractions of a millisecond).